# Для типа «односвязанный неизменяемый список» можно ли написать две функции: замены элемента в списке и объединения двух списков на C#?

Tags: c#, list, список, односвязный-список

В первый раз в жизни столкнулся с подобной задачей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В первый раз в жизни столкнулся с постом в котором скрин не просто куска кода, а еще и с текстом из другого поста. Вам уже отвечали здесь на этот же вопрос https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2606005.html с примером создания такого класса, примените ImmutableList.ToImmutableList Метод https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist.toimmutablelist?view=netcore-3.1 для того чтоб сделать его неизменяемым

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для замены элемента в неизменяемом списке нужно пройти по всему списку, заменить требуемое значение элемента, и затем полностью пересоздать список с новыми значениями.
Для объединения двух списков, соответственно, нужно сделать поочередный обход каждого из списков, объединение их значений, и пересоздать список с объединенными значениями.
Как реализуется работа с неизменяемым списком, вы можете ознакомиться [здесь](https://github.com/mono/ImmutableCollections/blob/master/System.Collections.Immutable/System.Collections.Immutable/ImmutableList.cs).